# Displacement the values in neue columns

Tags: excel, vba

**My intention:**

I try:

1- import an XML-Data and  move the value in column "Name" one step up. *Table-1 is looks similar after importing the XML data*.

2- displace the values in one row and select them and move to a new column. (Ford and Nr. with their number in columns D).

3- Where in row ha have "a" this row with

**What i have (Table-1) ↓: **

| Serial | Name | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 |  |  |  |
|  | John |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Ford |  |
|  |  |  | 666 |
|  |  | Nr. |  |
|  |  |  | 345 |
| 005 |  |  |  |
|  | Thomas |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Ford |  |
|  |  |  | 6986 |
|  |  | Nr. |  |
|  |  |  | 0202 |

**What I want (Table-2)↓:**

| Serial | Name | Ford | Nr. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | 666 | 345 |
| 002 | Thomas | 6986 | 0202 |

**MY Code for Import XML-Data (it works):**

```
Private Sub CommandButton_XML_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '__________________________________
    
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ChooseFIle As Variant
    Dim TargetSheetName As String
    Dim TargetCellAddress As String
   
    TargetSheetName = Application.InputBox("Write a Sheet Name where you want to place the XML 
 Data ***Case Sensitive***", "Target Sheet Name")


    TargetCellAddress = Application.InputBox("Write a Cell Address from where XML Data Start Placing", "Target Cell Address")

   
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TargetSheetName)
    TargetSheet.UsedRange.Clear
   
    ChooseFIle = Application.GetOpenFilename("XML File (*.xml), *.xml", False)
   
    If ChooseFIle = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
   
    ThisWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=ChooseFIle, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=TargetSheet.Range(TargetCellAddress)
   
    MsgBox "Import is done. Das Hochladen der XML-Datei dauert eine weile", vbInformation
   
    
    Set TargetSheet = Nothing
    
    


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   

End Sub
```

It would be graceful if somebody help me to make a table like Table-2:

Comment: Can't understand the applied logic by which you want to configure your output data. At first glance, the data and/or titles seem a bit jumbled or even missing (e.g. where is `Thomas`?)- it would be helpful to edit the xml structure for better understanding, which node contents are written to which columns and to describe exactly the relations between column data and output (e.g. why e.g. `Three` or `CCC` aren't data but appear in title etc. etc.) @Jsmoka

Comment: @T.M.
I have edited my mistakes and tried to reform my question for better understanding. I can't change the Nodes of XML-Data.

Comment: You'll have to define the 4-columns data range (e.g. `Dim rng As Range` and `Set rng = ...` and assign it to a 1-based 2-dim datafield array after declaration `Dim data As Variant` like e.g. `data = rng.Value` as first step. Then you can loop through each array row with two separate counters (current rows & final rows) and reassign found values (referred to by row and column indices e.g. via `data(r,c)`) to a receiving array with similar boundaries. Eventually you'll write back the entire data to a resized range, e.g. `rng.resize(finalRows),4) = newData`. Try it searching other SO answers :-;

Comment: Thank your for your answer but i couldn’t understand what i have do! Its like learning swimming from a book!

Comment: Focus on one step after the other. It will help to search existing answers at SO how to assign range data to a datafield array and how to loop. - Can't promise you a complete and immediate answer, as SO isn't a free code writing site - try to edit some starting code of your own to resolve the core problem (even pseudo code)  and describe where precisely you get issues (which error?). Consider even deleting your answer and splitting it into partial questions having done basic research on existing answers. @Jsmoka Btw I don't assume columns C and D are a direct result of xml import, are they?

Comment: Such a code with issue i have enough but they doesn’t work correctly. The Results are exactly from XML

Comment: Please edit your post and show the relevant xml data structure to make the question reproducable; can't help feeling that the imported table structure you are showing is somehow messed up.